# on actual iOS device Admob not working for iOS apps while it works in simulator

Tags: admob

I am integrating Admob in the iOS application (iPhone and iPad: a universal app).
In beginning I check the admob works on simulator but when i install the app on device, app got crash and comment the admob code , app works fine. few days latter i uncomment the code and install the app in device it seems working on both device and see the different 2 adds in banner. few days latter again the same code got crash in device and works in simulator for admob.  now I comment the Admob code from all screen except one screen, app working now if i not visit the screen that have the admob code uncommented.

Please suggest me the solution.I am using below code.

AbMob = [[GADBannerView alloc]
                 initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,768-50-90,
                                          GAD_SIZE_728x90.width,
                                      GAD_SIZE_728x90.height)];

```
AbMob.adUnitID = [Utility getADmobPublisherId];
AbMob.rootViewController = self;

[self.view addSubview:AbMob];
GADRequest *r = [[GADRequest alloc] init];
r.testing = YES;
//---------
r.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID,@"UDID1",@"UDID2",nil];
//----------
[AbMob loadRequest:r];
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this version.

```
AbMob = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(
    0.0,
    768-50-90,
    GAD_SIZE_728x90.width,
    GAD_SIZE_728x90.height)];

AbMob.adUnitID = [Utility getADmobPublisherId];
[AbMob setRootViewController:self];

[self.view addSubview:AbMob];
GADRequest *r = [GADRequest request];  // This takes care of reference counts for you.
r.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID,
                                          @"UDID1",
                                          @"UDID2",
                                          nil];
[AbMob loadRequest:r];
```